# Building Daylight Saving into a script to define Trading Opening Times Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, dst

I am trying to build into my strategy account of Daylight saving. The strategy is dependent on the opening hours of an exchange. (Not crypto).

The code I have is:

```
dst=0

t=time(timeframe.period,"0400-0500:23456")
t1=time(timeframe.period,"0500-0555:23456") 

//This resolves daylight saving back to 2016
dsfallback2020 = timestamp(2019,10,25,08,00)
dsspringfor2020 = timestamp(2020,03,29,08,00)
dsfallback2019 = timestamp(2019,10,27,08,00)
dsspringfor2019 = timestamp(2019,03,31,08,00)
dsfallback2018 = timestamp(2018,10,28,08,00)
dsspringfor2018 = timestamp(2018,03,25,08,00)
dsfallback2017 = timestamp(2017,10,25,08,00)
dsspringfor2017 = timestamp(2017,03,26,08,00)
dsfallback2016 = timestamp(2017,10,30,08,00)
dsspringfor2016 = timestamp(2017,03,27,08,00)

if (t > dsspringfor2020 and t < dsfallback2020)
    dst:=1
else if (t > dsspringfor2019 and t < dsfallback2019)
    dst:=1
else if (t > dsspringfor2018 and t < dsfallback2018)
    dst:=1
else if (t > dsspringfor2018 and t < dsfallback2018)
    dst:=1
else
    na

if dst = 1
    t = time(timeframe.period,"0400-0500:23456")
    t1 = time(timeframe.period,"0500-0555:23456")  
    bgcolor(not na(t) ? color.green : na)
    H_Highbar = security('CAPITALCOM:UK100', '60', high[0]) 
    H_Lowbar = security('CAPITALCOM:UK100', '60', low[0])
    plot(series=not t1 ? na : H_Highbar, title='Session Open Price', color=color.green, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=0)
    plot(series=not t1 ? na : H_Lowbar, title='Buy Line', color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=0)
else
    t =time(timeframe.period,"0300-0400:23456")
    t1 = time(timeframe.period,"0400-0455:23456")
    bgcolor(not na(t) ? color.green : na)
    H_Highbar = security('CAPITALCOM:UK100', '60', high[0]) 
    H_Lowbar = security('CAPITALCOM:UK100', '60', low[0])
    plot(series=not t1 ? na : H_Highbar, title='Session Open Price', color=color.green, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=0)
    plot(series=not t1 ? na : H_Lowbar, title='Buy Line', color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=0)
```

It doesnt work. Hopefully you can see what I have been trying to do. Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 5):

I believe there's an easier way, using the hour() function.

For instance, we know that during standard time (non-DST) the time difference between New York and UTC is 5 hours, whereas during DST the time difference is 4 hours -- there's no DST in UTC. So:

HourNY = hour(time, "America/New_York")

HourUTC = hour(time, "UTC")

DST := HourUTC - HourUTC == 5 ? false : true

During standard time and between 12:00 and 12:59:59 in NY, HourNY will be equal to 12 and HourUTC will be equal to 17, and the difference is 5 (DST = false).

During DST and between 12:00 and 12:59:59 in NY, HourNY will be equal to 12 and HourUTC will be equal to 14, and the difference is 4 (DST = true).

Now, this will not work when it's after 19:00 in NY because it's the next day in UTC and HourUTC - HourUTC will give a negative number.

You can provide for this by testing only in the time period 0000-1859 NY time. However, a neater way of doing it in my opinion is by noticing that during standard time and between 19:00 and 23:59 HourUTC - HourUTC will equal -19 (and during DST it will equal -20), so that can be built into the code:

DST := HourUTC - HourNY == 5 or HourUTC - HourNY == -19 ? false : HourUTC - HourNY == 4 or HourUTC - HourNY == -20 ? true : na

And voila :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't find any other solution yet (:

Just to add to the post, to get to know if its DST in Europe, you can use the following code:

`int HourUTC = hour(time, "UTC")
int HourBLN = hour(time, "Europe/Berlin")
DST = (((HourUTC - HourBLN) == 22) or ((HourUTC - HourBLN) == -2)) ? true : false`